# How can i create a dynamic page using parameter in react + Json

Tags: json, reactjs, react-router-dom

How can i create a dynamic page using parameter in react + Json

in my code below i was able to map the json data and i need to create a dynamic url that create the /download page with the json details of the artist when i click on "GET MP3" button.

example: When i click GET MP3 a new tab will open with a url like this https:// mysite.com/
then on the download page i can get all the details from the {data.id}.

Please any idea on how to go around it?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import "../customcss/style.css";
import data from  "../artist/toptrending5.json";






const newdata = data.map((item) => {

    const searchDownloadData = `download?id=${item.id}&artist=${item.artist}&title=${item.title}&genre=${item.genre}&urldownload=${item.urldownload}`
    return (
        <>
                                          
<div id="playerbackground" key= {data.id} style={{marginTop:  '10px'}}>
      <div className="row" align="center">
           <div className="col">
               <img id="Playericon" src={ Playericon } />

            </div>

          <div className="col ">
                            
            <button id="music-play" type="button" className="btn btn-outline-warning"><b>Play</b></button>
           </div>

              <div className="col-5 " align="center">
                       <h6 id="music-title"><b> { data.artist} - { data.title }</b></h6>
              </div>

        <div  className="col player-col-sm-2" align="center">
                           
        <Link to={searchDownloadData}  rel=" noopener noreferrer" id="music-download" className="btn btn-outline-primary"><b> MP3 </b></Link>
             </div>
                            
             </div> 
                          
              </div>

          
                  </>
                  )
                }
              )

export default class Top5 extends Component {
  
        render() {
    return (
      <>

<h2 id="trendtop5" className="trendtop5">Top 10 Trending Bongo Music</h2>
   
      <div id="" className="container"> {newdata} </div>
      <div className="container" style={{marginTop: '10px', paddingRight: '10px' }} >
      <button  className="btn btn-outline-primary"  ><NavLink exact to="/artist">Explore More</NavLink></button>
      </div>
      <br />
  
      </>

   );
  }
}
```

Below is my router

```
<BrowserRouter>
  
    <div id="wrapper">
 <header id="header">
    <div className="container">

      <div id="logo" className="pull-left">
          <img id="logo" src={ logo } />
        <h1 id="h1home"><a href="/"><strong> Music</strong></a></h1>
        
      </div>
        
      <nav id="menu-button-nav">


        <ul id="nav" className="nav-menu">
           
            <li className="btn btn-warning"><NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
            <li className="btn btn-warning"><NavLink to="/justin">Just In</NavLink></li>
            <li className="btn btn-warning"><NavLink to="/artist">Artists</NavLink></li>
            <li className="btn btn-warning"><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
                 
        </ul>
        
      </nav>
      </div>
      
       </header>
</div>
 
     <div id="content" className="container" >

       
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/justin" component={Justin}/>
            <Route path="/artist" component={Artists}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/download" component={DownloadArtist}></Route></Route>
         </div>

     
   
       </BrowserRouter>
```

Below is my Json data that hold the artist details

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "artist": "Artist 1" ,
        "title": "tata",
        "genre": "rock",
        "urldownload" : "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1-"
    },
{
        "id":2,
        "artist": "Artist 1" ,
        "title": "tata",
        "genre": "rock",
        "urldownload" : "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1-"
    },
{
        "id":3,
        "artist": "Artist 1" ,
        "title": "tata",
        "genre": "rock",
        "urldownload" : "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1-"
    },
{
        "id":4,
        "artist": "Artist 1" ,
        "title": "tata",
        "genre": "rock",
        "urldownload" : "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1-"
    }

]
```

Download Page

```
class DownloadArtist extends Component {

  render() {
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const id = JSON.parse(url.searchParams.get("id"));
const artist = url.searchParams.get("artist");
const title = url.searchParams.get("title");
const genre = url.searchParams.get("genre");
const urldownload = url.searchParams.get("urldownload");


console.log(url)


    return (

    <>
             <section>
                <h1 id="artistComingSoon" className="center"> ADVERT!!!</h1>
              </section>


              <section>
              <div className="container">
                          <p> <strong>User ID: </strong>{id} </p>
                          <p> <strong>Artist Name: </strong>{artist}</p> 
                          <p> <strong>Title: </strong>{title} </p>
                          <p> <strong>Genre: </strong>{genre}</p>
                          <p> <strong>Download Link: </strong>{urldownload}</p>
                </div>
              </section>

       <section>
        <h1 id="artistComingSoon" className="center"> ADVERT!!!</h1>
      </section>
      </>
    );
  }
}
 
export default DownloadArtist;
```

**Updated**
**Solved**

Comment: Do you want to create this download page in your code or does it already exist?

Comment: it already exist

Comment: @MaatMa It already exist

Comment: Then you could use url parameter I think.

Comment: I think you need to add param to ur link, like ttps:// mysite.com/download/:slug

https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

So the dowload page will handling dowload/video download/mp3 and so on

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad can you show me how to write it

Comment: Sure, I will write the answer now and explan it...

Answer (score 0):

Your React app, wich is calling the download page, can pass parameter with the url. Your download page then can read those.

You can specify parameter with an "?" in your url. If you want to, you can send multiple parameter as well.

```
const url = `https://example.com/download/?id=${data.id}`
```

In your download page you can read those parameter with the URL class.

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const id = JSON.parse(url.searchParams.get("id"));
```

With your example it would be something like this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Route,
    NavLink,
    HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import "../customcss/style.css";
import data from "../artist/toptrending5.json";

const newdata = data.map((item) => {
    const url = `/download/?id=${item.id}`;
    return (
        <>
            <div id="playerbackground" key={item.id} style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
                <div className="row" align="center">
                    <div className="col">
                        <img id="Playericon" src={Playericon} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col ">
                        <button id="music-play" type="button" className="btn btn-outline-warning"><b>Play</b></button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-5 " align="center">
                        <h6 id="music-title"><b> {item.artist} - {item.title}</b></h6>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col player-col-sm-2" align="center">
                        <Link to={url} rel=" noopener noreferrer" id="music-download" className="btn btn-outline-primary"><b> MP3 </b></Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
)

export default class Top5 extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <h2 id="trendtop5" className="trendtop5">Top 10 Trending Bongo Music</h2>
                <div id="" className="container"> {newdata} </div>
                <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: '10px', paddingRight: '10px' }} >
                    <button className="btn btn-outline-primary"  ><NavLink exact to="/artist">Explore More</NavLink></button>
                </div>
                <br />
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: please can you explain better am kind of lost

Comment: Did the upate helped you?

Comment: No i am still stuck, i am getting undefine at the end of the url

Comment: I just saw there are two declarations of "data". Try to change de declaration inside of the map to "item" or something like that. And are the titles displayed correctly?

Comment: The mapping is for the live search.... it map the json data and list the keyword search. so i want onclick on the MP3 button it takes me to the download.js with the json data/values to be use in the download.js page

Comment: Could you try my example above? Is the url parameter still undefined?

Comment: this is what i get on the browser url "http://localhost:3000/download/?id=1" i was able to get the data on the url. so how can i print out the data on the body of the page. i tried {item.id} didnt work i also tried {data.id} same result.

Comment: You need to parse the url and use the searchItem function. Thats the second code box in my example.

Comment: i can only get the id when i parse... i cant get the other value

Comment: What other value do you mean? I thought there is only the id. If you want to provide more parameter, you need to seperate them with an "&"

Comment: like this '/download/?id=${item.id}&${item.artist}&{item.link}'

Comment: You need to give those parameters a name. Like this '/download/?id=${item.id}&artist=${item.artist}&link={item.link}'

Answer (score 0):

To handling URL routes in react, we are already use React Router

React Router allow us to manage routes and handling url with dynamic behavior, so that, what we need to do is:

1. Build route
2. Build url which its follow this route

For Example:

```
<Route path={`download/:type`}>
          <myComponent />
        </Route>
```

================

```
<li>
            <Link to=`/download/mp3`>Download MP3</Link>
          </li><li>
            <Link to=`/download/video`>Download Video</Link>
          </li>
```

If you do this, you will send url params and you can fetch it easy by this:

```
const {type} = useParams();
```